# Custom authentication middleware: InvalidOperationException on failed authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I want to authenticate calls to my ASP.NET Core 1.0 application using a HTTP Header like `Authorization ToggledKey 10079a4c-d27e-4898-915a-968850c756ef`

The idea being that I can issue API keys and people can use them, revoke them, etc. I want just a very simple key - I don't want to get into OAuth, IdentityServer, or anything else.

I followed [this tutorial](http://geeklearning.io/how-to-deal-with-identity-when-testing-an-asp-net-core-application/) which talks about how to "fake" a successful response for testing purposes, and I ended up with the code below:

```
public class TestAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationOptions  
{
    public virtual ClaimsIdentity Identity { get; } = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        // Other claims omitted for brevity
    }, "Toggled");

    public TestAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        this.AuthenticationScheme = "ToggledAuthenticationMiddleware";
        this.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    }
}

public class TestAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<TestAuthenticationOptions>  
{
    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                                        new ClaimsPrincipal(Options.Identity),
                                        new AuthenticationProperties(),
                                        this.Options.AuthenticationScheme);

        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(authenticationTicket));
    }
}

public class TestAuthenticationMiddleware : AuthenticationMiddleware<TestAuthenticationOptions>  
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public TestAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<TestAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        : base(next, options, loggerFactory, System.Text.Encodings.Web.UrlEncoder.Default)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    protected override AuthenticationHandler<TestAuthenticationOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new TestAuthenticationHandler();
    }
}
```

To begin with I'm just trying to get a hard-coded successful authentication which will allow me to see the user with `User.Identity.Name` and a hard-coded failed authentication to let me see a `401 Unauthorized` - just to understand how it works.

Added into `Configure` method:

```
app.UseMiddleware<TestAuthenticationMiddleware>(); 
app.UseMvc();
```

So far, so good, it works - `[Authorize]` attribute goes on a controller and I get a GUID in `User.Identity.Name`

**The problem:**

When I change for a failed response:

```
return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Auth Failed!"));
//return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(authenticationTicket));
```

Instead of a 401 I get a 500 with the following exception:

```
Unknown error responding to request: InvalidOperationException:
System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.<ChallengeAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```

I do see the authentication failure in the middleware logged:

```
[Information] ToggledAppServices.TestAuthenticationMiddleware: ToggledAuthenticationMiddleware was not authenticated. Failure message: Auth failed!
```

So I can see that it did use the middleware, fail the authentication, but then also see just before the `InvalidOperationException`:

```
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
```

After this though I'm pretty confused. What can I do to make my middleware the "only" point of authentication, and if it fails, to return a 401 instead of trying to do something more and failing with an InvalidOperationException?

Full logs:

```
[Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Hosting starting 
[Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Hosting started 
START RequestId: 52c7358f-e50a-11e7-a5a6-b3632cca0b75 Version: $LATEST
Incoming GET requests to /api/values
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting GET https://www.example.com/api/controller application/json 
[Information] ToggledAppServices.TestAuthenticationMiddleware: ToggledAuthenticationMiddleware was not authenticated. Failure message: Auth failed! 
[Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter: Request successfully matched the route with name '' and template 'api/values'. 
[Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executing action ToggledAppServices.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (ToggledAppServices) 
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Authorization failed for user: . 
[Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'. 
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (). 
Unknown error responding to request: InvalidOperationException:
System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.<ChallengeAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.<ProcessRequest>d__15.MoveNext()
InvalidOperationException:
System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.<ChallengeAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.<ProcessRequest>d__15.MoveNext()

[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 7360.5673ms 0 
Response Base 64 Encoded: False
END RequestId: 52c7358f-e50a-11e7-a5a6-b3632cca0b75
```

Comment: You’re using ASP.NET Core 1.x, right? Is there a reason why you cannot use 2.0? The authentication stack got a lot easier to customize in 2.0.

Comment: @poke It's running in AWS Lambda so currently it's the only supported version. I'm looking forward to them bringing out support for 2 - I know it's been announced but not ready for use yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.Internal.DefaultAuthenticationManager.<ChallengeAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```

This suggests that the *authentication* of your authentication handler is working properly and a challenge result is properly created as a result of the failed authentication.

So now, the default challenge authentication handler should run to process the challenge request. However, there is no default challenge scheme configured, so this fails.

In order to tell your `TestAuthenticationHandler` to also handle challenge requests, you should set the `AutomaticChallenge` option of your `TestAuthenticationOptions` type to `true`:

```
// handle authenticate requests by default
AutomaticAuthenticate = true;

// handle challenge requests by default
AutomaticChallenge = true;
```

Then, your handler will run for challenge requests and since you don’t provide a custom implementation, [the default behavior](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationHandler.cs#L344) will just generate a 401 HTTP response.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you - I've burned so many hours with that :)

Comment: Authentication can be a pain – I hope you have a chance to upgrade to ASP.NET Core 2 soon! :)